# Word 2010 template conditional drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, ms-word

I am trying to create a Microsoft Word template that has two drop down menus. One conditioned on the other. For this reason I am using the Legacy Tools in Word.

I can't get the drop-down menu to, well, drop down. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

The menu I've created has multiple options but when I click on it, nothing drops down.

I've tried:

- turning 'Design Mode' on/off.
- Creating a blank word document from the template
- Using .dotx and .dot
- Searching online through Microsoft forums/support

No Luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled document protection? Dropdowns only work when the document is protected.